# JFreeChart XYAreaChart setting Domain Axis

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a dynamic area chart which is implemented with w mouse wheel listener tu put data on my chart through the time, I want to set my domain axis for 10 seconds only because my chart is showin all data from the beginning but I want to display only the 10 last seconds.
How to do that?
Here's my code:

```
 final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Data");

    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);

    // Creation du area chart
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart("Fun Meter", "", "",
            dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);


    final JLabel a = new JLabel();
    // Un chartpanel pour contenir le area chart
    ChartPanel CP = new ChartPanel(chart);

    // creation d'objet plot pour ajustement de tout ce qui est graphique
    XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();

    // la couleur degradée pour le remplissage du area chart
    GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 100.0f, new Color(50, 205,
            50), 0.0f, 100.0f, Color.red);

    xyPlot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);
    xyPlot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.black);
    xyPlot.setForegroundAlpha(0.75f);

    GradientPaint gp1 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 100.0f, Color.black, 0.0f,
            1000.0f, new Color(153, 153, 153));

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(gp1);

    CP.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

            Integer rx = e.getWheelRotation();
            Wheel = Wheel - rx;
                    }
    });

    new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            series.add(series.getItemCount(), Wheel);
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a [`DynamicTimeSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/DynamicTimeSeriesCollection.html#DynamicTimeSeriesCollection%28int,%20int,%20org.jfree.data.time.RegularTimePeriod%29), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513). The `nMoments` constructor parameter specifies the number of `TimePeriod` units to be retained.